# How do I programatically play an webm audio I just recorded in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, webrtc, mediarecorder

I just recorded a piece of audio and I want to play it with pure Javascript code.

So this is my code:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true},function(stream){
    var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    recorder.start(1000);

    recorder.ondataavailable = function(e){
        console.log(e.data);
        // var buffer = new Blob([e.data],{type: "video/webm"});
    };
});
```

What do I have to do in `ondataavailable` so that I can play the audio chunks stored in memory without and `audio` or `video` tag in HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see why you don't want an audio or video element, but anyway, the first steps are the same.

The `MediaRecorder.ondataavailable` event will fire at regular intervals, and will contain a `data` property containing a chunk of the recorded media.
You need to store these chunks, in order to be able to merge them in a single Blob at the end of the recording.
To merge them, you would simply call `new Blob(chunks_array)`, where `chunks_array` is an Array containing all the chunk Blobs you got from `dataavailable.data`.

Once you've got this final Blob, you can use it as a normal media, e.g, either play it in a MediaElement thanks to the `URL.createObjectURL` method, or convert it to an ArrayBuffer and then decode it through the WebAudio API or whatever other ways you'd like.

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
.then(recordStream)
.catch(console.error);

function recordStream(stream){
  const chunks = []; // an Array to store all our chunks
  const rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  rec.ondataavailable  = e => chunks.push(e.data);
  rec.onstop = e => {
    stream.getTracks().forEach(s => s.stop());
    finalize(chunks);
  };
  rec.start();
  setTimeout(()=>rec.stop(), 5000); // stop the recorder in 5s
}
function finalize(chunks){
  const blob = new Blob(chunks);
  playMedia(blob);
}
function playMedia(blob){
  const ctx = new AudioContext();
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = e =>  ctx.decodeAudioData(fileReader.result)
  .then(buf => {
    btn.onclick = e => {
      const source = ctx.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = buf;
      source.connect(ctx.destination);
      source.start(0);
    };
    btn.disabled = false;
  });
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" disabled>play</button>
```

[And as a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZMdjUn3L0p8EAnySOR99?p=preview) for chrome and its heavy iframes restrictions.

Comment: Hey thanks. Cant i reproduce a chunk instead of the whole sequence? I actually was looking for a way to reproduce it with the objects and methods of the Web Audio Api, like `audioContext` `audioBuffer` `audioBufferSourceNode`

Comment: @VictorFerreira You would always at least need all the prior chunks until the first one: e.g if you recorded long enough to get 10 chunks, you could build a file from only the 5 firsts, but not from the fifth alone. Metadata are held in the first chunk.